# Sharing image via LinkedIn API v2 appears cropped and different from sharing on www.linkedin.com

Tags: linkedin-api

When an image is shared to a profile (not a Company) via the LinkedIn API v2 it displays as if it is cropped:

[image]

However, when I upload and share the same image on `www.linkedin.com` to my profile it does **not** show as cropped and the entire image is shown:

[image]

This is happening for both square and rectangular images. Looking a bit more closely it seems that LinkedIn is applying a different `padding-top` to the images shared via the API compared to those shared/uploaded on `www.linkedin.com`.

#### From API

[image]

#### From www.linkedin.com

[image]

Anyone else seeing this issue? It would be nice if images were presented consistently.

UPDATE: this is also happening when sharing to company pages, not just profiles.

Answer (score 5):

An easy answer is to choose images with a 1.91:1 aspect ratio. I have found that those images do not get cropped nor [pillarboxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)#Pillarboxing_and_windowboxing).

In case that's not an option, the workaround I use is resending the image as a thumbnail, including the original image dimensions.

Here's an example of posting a 1000x600 image that is located at `https://example.com/image.png`

After [uploading the image as rich media](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/rich-media-shares#upload) and getting the URN (`urn:li:richMediaSummary:PNG-IMG-54f022ae8b3f4d479e925b4df68e19`) from the response, [post the Share](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/shares/share-api#post) with the URN as the content entity, and the url and dimensions of the image as a thumbnail.

```
{
    "owner": "urn:li:person:324_kGGaLE",
    "distribution": {
        "linkedInDistributionTarget": {}
    },
    "content": {
        "contentEntities": [
            {
                "entity": "urn:li:richMediaSummary:PNG-IMG-54f022ae8b3f4d479e925b4df68e19",
                "thumbnails": [
                    {
                        "imageSpecificContent": {
                            "width": 1000,
                            "height": 600
                        },
                        "resolvedUrl": "https:\/\/example.com\/image.png"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```